# Errors on app and simulator not starting, Xcode 12.2

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-previews

I have a question. My page is giving me an error. It says:

```html
Fatal error: Couldn't parse Rest.json as Array<Restaurant>:
dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}))): file SaiMirrasKitchen/ModelData.swift, line 30
```

And what value to put to fix the simulator in the RestaurantRow.swift file, line 21?
Thanks,
Harri

[Github Respoitory](https://github.com/HSSwift/SwiftCode.git)

Comment: Hey Harry welcome to stackoverflow. Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Try checking for errors in your JSON with a tool like [this](https://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json string is not valid , for your example it should be :

```
{"restaurants": [
    {
        "id":1001,
        "name":"Chapathi",
        "imageName":"Chapathi",
        "description":"Chapathi is a type of roti bread that is served all around the world.It is made of of wheat flour, oil, and water. Rolled and placed on a tawa.",
       "category":"Tiffin"
    },
    {
        "id":1002,
        "name":"Chapathi",
        "imageName":"Chapathi",
        "description":"Chapathi is a type of roti bread that is served all around the world.It is made of of wheat flour, oil, and water. Rolled and placed on a tawa.",
       "category":"Tiffin"
    }
  ]
}
```

and

```
let restaurants:Restaurants = load("Rest.json")
```